# generating tableview from plist file

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist

i know the feature of generating a nice looking table view for the iPhone's system settings menu by creating a Settings.bundle with a plist file where you define all the different elements for the table view (type, key, default value etc..)
My Question:
is there any way to create such a table view within the application? 
...to be quick and avoid bothering with the IB ;)
Thanks in advance!

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [inAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) will give you a nice start.